# How do I return a collection of related equal models?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I currently have a restaurant table in which I store restaurants and its branches. Note, there is only one table for restaurants and branches.

So the relationship I have set up is:

```
public function branches()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class);
}
```

When I tinker `$restaurant->branches`, it returns the correct branches. But when I try to eager load the relationship like:

```
$restaurant->with('branches')->get();
```

It will return every single restaurant that is stored in the table when I am only looking for a collection of parent and branch restaurants.

How can I accomplish such a behavior where a collection is returned of parent and branches?

Comment: can you put parent specifier in parent column of restaurant ?

Comment: you want to get restarant like $restaurant->with('branches')->where('parent',0)->get(); here 0 is indicate restaraunt  is parent not branch

Answer (score 0):

Provide the foriegn key,

```
public function branches1()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'foreign_key');
}
```

Then use

```
$restaurants::with('branches1')->get();
```

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. The relationship works and is correct, even without the foreign key. What you posted will eager load the branches, but it will also add every single restaurant in the table.

Comment: then u should be providing where condition on restaurants table

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I think its better if your restaurant table schema like below

```
------------------------------
id | name | parent | created_at
------------------------------
```

then create a relation for branches

```
function branches(){
   return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent');
}
```

now you can access the branches like

```
foreach($restaurent->branches as $branch){
  echo $branch->name;
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Using `with()` will load all the rows. If you have already fetched the model you can use `$restaurant->load('branches');` 
It will load the related relations for you.

and secondly `$restaurant->branches` will return the collection but for eager loading, you have to  do this

```
Resturant::with('branches')->where('id',$id)->first();
```

Or you can use

```
Resturant::with(['branches' => function($query) use ($id){
$query->where('id',$id);
})->where('id',$id)->first();
```